# How does the static Transport.send() method manage its connections?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a question about the static `javax.mail.Transport.send(Message msg)` method. The documentation only says "Note that send is a static method that creates and manages its own connection". Does it mean that the method also closes the connection? What's the difference with the non-static `sendMessage(Message msg, Address[] addresses)` method?

I have had a couple of errors in production due to bad syntax email addresses passed by the glassfish 3 server turns really slow. I want to discard any connection leaks.

Comment: The reference implementation of JavaMail is open source. Have you looked at the implementation? See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/javamail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method opens the connection, sends the message, and closes the connection.  And yes, the connection is also closed if there's an exception sending the message.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now, when do I use the static method and when the non-static one?

Comment: The static method is there for convenience.  if you only need to send one message infrequently, use it.  If you need to send a lot of messages all together, it's better to open the connection once, send each message, then close the connection.